# CSS3 expand row item height without affect the full row height

Tags: css, css-grid

I got an **ul** with multiple **li**, what I need is that each **li** fit 50% of the view-port width, floating to the right, and a dynamic height, because could be expanded and collapsed, but without affect the full row.

---

**This is how it should look normally:**

[image: all items collapsed]

---

**This is how it should look with an item expanded:**

[image: an item expanded]

---

I tried in so many ways but without successful. Is important to me not to use javascript for it, just CSS.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. We can help you more effectively if we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check this link: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/YorkFord/pen/ooZoop)

```
<div class="collapse">

  <input id="big-text-collapse" type="checkbox">
  <label for="big-text-collapse" onclick>Big text</label>

  <div class="collapse__content">
    <strong>I'm always collapsible</strong>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut volutpat lectus mi, vel consectetur massa vulputate in. Donec vestibulum, dui non facilisis congue, ex nisi bibendum urna, in lacinia enim dolor sed risus. Nunc tristique malesuada mauris, at
      accumsan velit aliquam vitae. Sed ultricies risus sit amet velit consequat lacinia. Sed non ornare erat. Suspendisse convallis velit dapibus orci sollicitudin malesuada.
    </p>
  </div>
```